# The exterior algebra of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

I need to confirm that I have understood the definition of the exterior algebra of a vector space correctly. I would be very grateful if someone could confirm that this is correct, or point out any issues.

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$. Then the tensor algebra $$T(V):=K\oplus V\oplus (V\otimes V)\oplus(V\otimes V\otimes V)\oplus\cdots$$ has elements which are finite sums of elementary tensors $x_1\otimes\cdots\otimes x_n$, where $x_i\in V$ (including elements of $K$ for the '$0$-tensors').

Then we obtain the exterior algebra $\bigwedge(V)$ by setting $x\otimes x=0$ for all $x\in V$ (within $T(V)$) and writing the image of $x_1\otimes\cdots\otimes x_n$ under the quotient by the ideal generated by elements of the form $x\otimes x$ as $x_1\wedge\cdots\wedge x_n$ (so that $x\wedge x=0$ for all $x\in V$).

Any issues here?

Comment: This looks fine. For more details and to compare see  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra). Perhaps the universal property should be mentioned, too.

Comment: Yes, this is fine. It's worth knowing that the two-sided ideal generated by the relations $x \otimes x = 0$ can be described more explicitly: it is spanned, as a vector space, by tensors of the form $x_1 \otimes \dots \otimes x_n$ where $x_1, \dots x_n$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: The exterior algebra corresponds to the antisymetric part of  the tensor algebra.  
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AntisymmetricPart.html
A formula for the wedge product (in Ricci notation) can be written as: 

$M_{a_{1}a_{2}\dots a_{m}} \wedge N_{b_{1}b_{2}\dots b_{n}} = M_{[a_{1}a_{2}\dots a_{m}}  N_{b_{1}b_{2}\dots b_{n}]} $

Comment: We can use that to derive:
$x_1 \wedge x_2 = \frac{1}{2}(x_{1}\otimes x_{2} - x_{2}\otimes x_{1})$ and

$x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge x_{3} = \frac{1}{6}((x_{1}\otimes x_{2} \otimes x_{3}  + x_{2}\otimes x_{3} \otimes x_{1} + x_{3}\otimes x_{1} \otimes x_{2} ) - (x_{1}\otimes x_{3} \otimes x_{2}  + x_{2}\otimes x_{1} \otimes x_{3} + x_{3}\otimes x_{2} \otimes x_{1} ))$

Comment: I prefer this to the quotient approach,  as it gives a more concrete intuition of the exterior algebra as subset of the tensor algebra.

Comment: @user3257842 The exterior algebra only corresponds to the antisymmetric tensors in characteristic 0; in any positive characteristic you do not have this correspondence.